# Concat datetime object with string

Tags: python, django, pymongo

I have following data and I want to create pymongo query in string format.

```
def epoch_to_date(epoach):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoach / 1000)

start_date = epoch_to_date(params.get('start_date'))
end_date = epoch_to_date(params.get('end_date'))
query = "collection.find({'code':"+obj.uuid+", createdDate: { $gte: "+start_date+", $lte: "+end_date+" } },{'_id': False}).sort('createdDate', -1).limit(100)"
```

but I'm not able to convert datetime object in string format it is giving me following error

> query = "collection.find({'code':"+obj.uuid+", createdDate: { $gte:
>   "+start_date+", $lte: "+end_date+" } },{'_id':
>   False}).sort('createdDate', -1).limit(100)" TypeError: coercing to
>   Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.datetime found

Can you tell me how can I use this datetime object in string format.

Comment: Use `start_date.strftime()` with your desired date format.

Comment: but pymongo not support date string format

Comment: What kind of format do you need? For example `datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%y')` will output the string `'01-03-20'`